# Stack Bar Plot with Numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to graph some datas with stack bar using matplotlib.

I wrote a code and it works perfectly without numbers;

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 5
menMeans = [20, 35, 30, 35, 27]
womenMeans = [25, 32, 34, 20, 25]
ind = np.arange(N)
width = 0.35

p1 = plt.bar(ind, menMeans, width, color='#d62728')
p2 = plt.bar(ind, womenMeans, width, bottom=menMeans)

plt.ylabel('Scores')
plt.title('Scores by group and gender')
plt.xticks(ind, ('G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5'))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 81, 10))
plt.legend((p1[0], p2[0]), ('Men', 'Women'))

plt.show()
```

And that is the picture of the graph

[image]

But I want to show every bar's numbers in the middle of them like this:

[image]

I tried to edit my code like this;

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 5
menMeans = [20, 35, 30, 35, 27]
womenMeans = [25, 32, 34, 20, 25]
ind = np.arange(N)
width = 0.35

p1 = plt.bar(ind, menMeans, width, color='#d62728')
p2 = plt.bar(ind, womenMeans, width, bottom=menMeans)

plt.ylabel('Scores')
plt.title('Scores by group and gender')
plt.xticks(ind, ('G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5'))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 81, 10))
plt.legend((p1[0], p2[0]), ('Men', 'Women'))
for index, data in enumerate(menMeans):
    plt.text(x=index, y=data + 1, s=f"{data}", fontdict=dict(fontsize=20))
for index, data in enumerate(womenMeans):
    plt.text(x=index, y=data + 1, s=f"{data}", fontdict=dict(fontsize=20))
plt.show()
```

But it shows like this

[image]

Where is my fault? Can you fix it ?

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks for edits, but I didn't find in anywhere how can I add these pictures like this format. how can I do?

Comment: You have to have a minimum reputation so that when images are displayed, otherwise they will only be placed as links, you just have to wait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `horizontalalignment='center'` and `verticalalignment='center'` and then use the correct values for the y-offset. This is one way of doing it. You can also use short forms as `ha` and `va`

```
for index, data in enumerate(menMeans):
    plt.text(x=index, y=data/2, s=f"{data}", ha='center',
             va='center', fontsize=20)
    plt.text(x=index, y=data + (womenMeans[index]/2), s=f"{womenMeans[index]}", ha='center',
             va='center',fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

[image]

EDIT: Answering your second question, add the following line which will give you the below figure

```
plt.text(x=index, y=data + womenMeans[index]+1, s=f"{data+womenMeans[index]}", 
         ha='center',fontsize=20)
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks. But I have 1 more question. If I want to show sum of every columns (for ex. 20+25 = 45 = the sum) to top of the bar, how can I add this line?

Comment: @Wicaledon : Check the edited answer. I added a solution to your second question